# Where's all the stuff I bought?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I recently made quite a few purchases in *Assassin's Creed 3*.

Specifically, weapons and outfits. The problem I'm currently facing, however, is that I cannot find any of them! I've checked every room in the Homestead, but my new toys seem to be hiding! No doubt they're terrified of blood.

**Where are all of my purchased weapons and clothes hiding?**

Comment: I honestly haven't bothered with buying much (I'm still relatively early in the game doing side missions) but did you check the basement?

Comment: @Shinrai I did. Checked every inch of the interior of the house, and didn't see anything. =( There's a place on the wall that made me think outfits went there, but they're all empty.

Comment: I could have sworn I saw some weapons on the racks in the side room in the basement...I'll have to check later, I honestly don't remember.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You change into your purchased finery and equip those fabulous weapons in the same place you bought them, i.e. any peddler. Once bought, you simply click equip on the item and you will be wearing it. This also works for the various found items as well.

You can also change into a selection of outfits and weapons in the basement of the Manor after the end of the game. For some reason, before then the basement will show the outfits but not allow you to equip them. You browse the outfits by approaching the case directly behind the training dummy and the weapons are located in the bottom of the L on the same level.

Comment: I found this to be the case with the purchased outfits, but the weapons I was able to choose at the peddlars or the basement of the Homestead.  No idea what all the racks for outfits are for however.

Comment: Over the course of the game you can pick up several different outfits that appear there. I know preorder/special edition stuff had one or more outfits too so I assume that its the "special" outfits that go there. I was quite disappointed too because I wanted to see all the outfits I bought in the shop side by side to decide which I liked most. :(

Comment: @sarge_smith Sorry for the delay here, been a bit preoccupied lately. Is that the *only* place to swap weapons/clothing?

Comment: @fluttershy It was, but then I found another :) I have updated the answer.

Comment: After the end of the game!? Whaaaaat!? =( Stupid Ubisoft...